# Searching for a phrase including square brackets - how to make it work?

Tags: support, search

The general reason I'm asking is the small heap of duplicates to [this popular Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147165/why-does-assigning-to-an-empty-list-e-g-raise-no-error). The heap is evergrowing, including e.g. this duplicate [posted just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796615/why-is-a-valid-statement-in-python).

The *specific* reason I'm asking is that **finding the "canonical" question is hard - using `python [] =`, `python []`, `python "[] ="`, etc., leeds to no sensible matches**.

Is this a feature? A bug relating to the special semantics of square brackets in the search field (due to tags)*? **How can this situation be remedied?**

PS. Apologies if this a general SE question and should be on the SE Meta.

*this one is solvable by modifying the indexer a bit, at least I think so...

Comment: Search for `python array` instead? (Are those arrays? I dunno python)

Comment: @Cerbrus It’s called a list in Python. And if you try to search for that, you get loads of different valid questions.

Comment: There we go. Search for `python list` instead. Thanks for the correction, @poke!

Comment: @Cerbrus : beside what poke has already said - *I* know where the question is. **The problem is lots of people don't, and obviously can't find it.** There have been many duplicates like the example provided, it's not just a fluke. And anyway, are you saying that `[]` shouldn't be searchable? What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Also note that this question is less about us finding the correct duplicate (we from the Python room have a pretty solid way to collect [canonical questions](http://sopython.com/canon/)); but rather to prevent new users from posting a duplicate simply by making the question easier to find.

Comment: `[]` are also used to search for tags, like `[python]`, I doubt it's even (reliably) possible to support searches like that.

Comment: Related question on Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken